# Does anybody know what the xcode file "InfoPlist.strings (English)" is?

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript

Does anyone know what the file `InfoPlist.strings` is for? It is in Xcode 3.2. It is a Cocoa app in Applescript.

Comment: First tell me why are you using xcode2.0, we all are working on 4.5 and even few on 4.6

Comment: Well, Sorry. but this is an old computer and i can not work out how to download the new one. it must be nearly the same anyway!

Comment: Is assembly language same as objective-C ? From xcode2.0 a lot of changes is been in Xcode ide as well as in objective-c, frameworks, clang, llvm, etc etc.

Comment: Suddenly your question changed from Xcode2.0 to 3.2!!!

Comment: I made a mistake in typing!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> An information property list file is a structured text file that
> contains essential configuration information for a bundled executable.
> The file itself is typically encoded using the Unicode UTF-8 encoding
> and the contents are structured using XML. The root XML node is a
> dictionary, whose contents are a set of keys and values describing
> different aspects of the bundle. The system uses these keys and values
> to obtain information about your app and how it is configured. As a
> result, all bundled executables (plug-ins, frameworks, and apps) are
> expected to have an information property list file.
>
> By convention, the name of an information property list file is
> Info.plist.
>
> Localized values are not stored in the Info.plist file itself.
> Instead, you store the values for a particular localization in a
> strings file with the name InfoPlist.strings. You place this file in
> the same language-specific project directory that you use to store
> other resources for the same localization. The contents of the
> InfoPlist.strings file are the individual keys you want localized and
> the appropriately translated value. The routines that look up key
> values in the Info.plist file take the user’s language preferences
> into account and return the localized version of the key (from the
> appropriate InfoPlist.strings file) when one exists. If a localized
> version of a key does not exist, the routines return the value stored
> in the Info.plist file.
>
> For example, the TextEdit app has several keys that are displayed in
> the Finder and thus should be localized. Suppose your information
> property list file defines the following keys:
>
> ```xml
> <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key> 
> <string>TextEdit</string>
> <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key> 
> <string>Copyright ¬© 1995-2009, Apple Inc.,All Rights Reserved.</string>
> ```
>
> The French localization for
> TextEdit then includes the following strings in the `InfoPlist.strings`
> file of its `Contents/Resources/French.lproj` directory:
>
> ```
> CFBundleDisplayName = "TextEdit";
> NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright © 1995-2009 Apple Inc.\nTous droits réservés.";
> ```

From [developer.Apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html)